# Images uploaded to Azure blob storage unavailable when browsing by direct URL

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I have uploaded a number of images to a Blob container on an Azure storage account of type StorageV2 (general purpose v2).

These were uploaded programmatically. Here's the code I used:

```
public Task CopyFile(string fileName, string targetPath)
{
    var blobRef = Container.GetBlockBlobReference(targetPath);

    blobRef.Properties.ContentType = GetContentType(fileName);

    return blobRef.UploadFromFileAsync(fileName);
}

public string GetContentType(string fileName)
{
    var provider = new FileExtensionContentTypeProvider();

    if (!provider.TryGetContentType(fileName, out var contentType))
    {
        contentType = "application/octet-stream";
    }

    return contentType;
}
```

`Container` is an initialized `CloudBlobContainer` instance.

When I use the Storage Explorer I can see the uploaded files. If I view the properties of any file it lists a Uri property. However, if I copy the value (a URL) and paste into a browser I see the following error page:

```
<Error>
    <Code>ResourceNotFound</Code>
    <Message>
        The specified resource does not exist. RequestId:12485818-601e-0017-6f69-56c3df000000 Time:2019-08-19T08:35:13.2123849Z
    </Message>
</Error>
```

But if I double-click the file in Storage Explorer it downloads the image correctly. The URL it uses is the same as the one I copied earlier as far as I could tell, except for some additional querystrings that look like this: `?sv=2018-03-28&ss=bqtf&srt=sco&sp=rwdlacup&se=2019-08-19T16:49:38Z&sig=%2FJs7VnGKsjplalKXCcl0XosgUkPWJccg0qdvCSZlDSs%3D&_=1566204636804`

I assume this must mean my blobs are not publically available, but I can't find any setting that will make my images available publically at their known URI. Can anyone point me in the right direction here? Thank you.

Comment: Could you tell me your storage container access level? For more details, please refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-manage-access-to-resources.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the access level that set to your container.
If that is a *Private* then you will have the error that you experiencing: ResourceNotFound

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately @test123 beat you to the answer though!

Comment: ya, especially by copying my image, that is dirty way

Comment: @getsetcode, you should mark Anton's answer, it's not good if someone copy others' answer.

Comment: Not sure what happened here. When I first saw the responses it looked like test123 had posted first. I also don't remember his/her answer containing an image. I thought maybe they copied your image into their answer after I'd accepted it, but right now the datestamps look like this answer went first. Pretty confused about this. I'll change this one to the answer and if @test123 wants to contest that, here's the place to do it.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, if you container's access level is Private, you use the direct url to access the blob then you will get the error. If you want to access it, you need to generate a SAS token for it. 
[image]

For more details, please refer to

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-manage-access-to-resources
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-sas-overview